# Why doesn't F# have Checked functions for floating point types?

Tags: casting, f#, floating-point

The built-in Checked module has conversions for all the integral types, but not for float (System.Double) or float32 (System.Single).

1. Why is this?
2. Are there any recommended alternatives if I need to cast numbers which may or may not be integral types to float or float32?
3. Are there any built-in functions for converting to integral types that also check that the input doesn't have a decimal part? It seems odd that `Checked.byte 3.1` returns `3` but `Checked.byte "3.1"` throws a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `float` and `float32` functions defined in `FSharp.Core.Operators`.

e.g.

```
let a = float 56
```

`FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked` includes functions which you can optionally use for performing checked rather than the default, unchecked, arithmetic defined in `FSharp.Core.Operators`.

`FSharp.Core.Operators` is included by default so those functions are automatically available but you can hide some of those functions with the alternative checked implementations by opening `Checked`.  When working with checked arithmetic, an overflow will raise an exception.

`float` and `float32` do not have checked alternatives defined in `FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked` because their behaviour doesn't change, these types are IEEE standardised with built-in special values to represent positive and negative infinity, nan, etc.  Integral types on the other hand, have no special values, they are just a range of numbers so the behaviour when you go outside the range can be handled in different ways.

We can see, for instance, if we look at the F# core source code, that for `float` the checked and unchecked addition functions are both translated into the IL op `add` while integer addition is translated into either `add.ovf` or `add` depending on the type of arithmetic used.

See:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3905

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4804

I don't know of any built in alternative function that rejects `3.1` but accepts `3.0`.  Presumably you could write something using `Option` to return `Some byte` if successful or `None` otherwise.  Note however that not all integer values are exactly representable by floating point numbers so you'd have to decide how you wanted to handle that.